# Need inline excel equation that does not change when sorting a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It is kind of hard to explain.. I am trying to create an inline excel formula that won't change the values if you sort on another column.

[image]

The third column is the equation:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,"Yes",IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>=1,A2<>A1),"Yes","No"))
```

If however, I sort on the 4th column, labelled sugar, the values in column 3 will change. I need a way around this. I want the values in column 3 to always stay the same. I know where the issue is coming from, it is the A2<>A1. If I can figure a way to remove that section the problem would be solved but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Wow, much simpler than I had. Could you explain how that doesn't just give Yes to all? from the looks of it, it only compares to Cell A2 and then only to Cell A3 so it would only give Yes.

Comment: Because of the `$` in `A$2:A2`... the range you're looking up expands as you drag down, to `A$2:A3`, `A$2:A4`, and so on.

Comment: Okay, so if it still technically changes the values in column 3 if I sort column 4, but the overall number of Yes and No stay the same. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes it does technically change the values in column 3, but the number of "Yes" does remain the same, as I suspected is what you actually wanted.